# Prove that $Au\cdot v = u\cdot A^Tv$ with standard inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let A be an $n$ x $n$ matrix and let $u$,$v$ $\in$ $\mathbb{F^n}$. Prove that $$Au\cdot v = u\cdot A^Tv$$

when <,> is the standard inner product.
 how can I prove it ?

Comment: $u\cdot v := u^Tv$ so
$Au\cdot v = (Au)^Tv = u^T(A^Tu) = u\cdot A^Tv$

Comment: and if above complex numbers?

Comment: Then it doesn't hold. $Au \cdot v = u\cdot A^* v$

Answer (score 1):

We have that
$$Au \cdot v=\sum_{i,j} A_{ij}u_j v_i $$
Can you express the other one?